# Nonlinear matrix equation solving in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

is it possible to solve below equation in *Mathematica*?

```
A.X+B.Exp[X]==C
```

`A`, `B` are square and constant matrices. `C` is a constant and column matrix. `X` is a column matrix which should be found. `Exp[]` acts element by element on `X`.

Comment: `C` is a "reserved word" in Mathematica, so don't use it — preferably, begin every user-defined symbol name with a lowercase character.

You could `NMinimise` (w.r.t. the components of `x`) an objective function defined as `#.#&[a.x+b.Exp[x]-c]` — i.e. the norm-squared of the difference between the left and right hand sides of your equation.

Answer (score 2):

Generally: Yes, as long as

1. you actually give the matrices `a` and `b`, as well as the vector `c`.
2. the resulting set of coupled equations actually *has* at least one solution.

With their elements named as usual `x={x1,x2}` etc., you then just do:

```
Solve[a.x + b.Exp[x] == c,{x1,x2}]
```

**Example:**

With `a={{1,0},{0,1}}`, `b={{0,1},{1,0}}`, `c={c1,c2}`, `x={x1,x2}` this will give you the solution:

```
{{x1 -> -I \[Pi] + Log[-c2 + x2]}}
```

i.e.: you are free to choose `x2` as you feel fit (in that very specific exemplary case).

Comment: Thank you @Jinxed. x has about 300 elements. is there any way to define whole elements of x like "X=sym('X',size(C))" in matlab?

Comment: @iliailiaey: Sure: You can create symbols for the vector elements e.g. by `x=Table[Symbol["x"<>ToString@i],{i,Length@c}]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `NSolve` since this is non-linear. But it might not be able to solve it. Find root can. Also, if you know range of solution expected, it might help.

```
m = 3;
A0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, m}];
B0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {m, m}];
x = {x1, x2, x3};
C0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, m];
eq = Thread[A0.x + B0.Exp[x] == C0];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 FindRoot[eq, {{x1, 0}, {x2, 0}, {x3, 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But `NSolve` could not do it

```
 NSolve[eq, x, Reals]
```

ps. I really do not know what `NSolve` can't solve nonlinear equations. But you can try the different methods on it to see if it helps. see ?NSolve for more information on the options.

Comment: Solve and NSolve are best suited for polynomial and not transcendental equations.